# MySQL integer rounds up or down, why can´t use decimals?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sqldatatypes

When I edit one of my integer columns to example 5,5 or 5.5 it always rounds up to 6.

How do I disable this? I want decimals like 5,5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop using integer, then! Integer is for whole numbers.

There are several options for fractioned numbers: float, double, decimal...

Decimal allows you to define the desired precision.

Comment: What is the differences between float, double and decimal?

Comment: Read here. It wil help you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: It's hard to recommend a type without knowing your app intents. Try changing to double, something tells me that will fit you...

Answer (score 2):

If you use an integer field how do you expect to store decimal?

Use decimal type with the desired number of decimal digits.

Take a look at the [numeric types that mysql support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

Comment: I tried the decimal but then again: 0 row(s) affected.
Note: #1265 Data truncated for column 'pilot' at row 1

Comment: I have changed the integer column to decimal and updated a row with the digit 5,5 and also tried 5.5

Comment: You have to use the dot and not the comma. If you're sure that your table now has a decimal field, you can assign it 5.5.

Comment: What means: Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column pilot' at row 1

Answer (score 1):

Beats the purpose of integer doesnt it, change the column type to float or double

```
alter table table_name change col_name col_name Float(M,D);
```

M= total digits
D = Digits  after decimal